# JS: higher order functions and map,reduce and filter

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand higher order functions.  I keep seeing the definition as “a function that accepts or returns another function” and map,reduce and filter are given as an example.  Does that basically mean map, reduce and filter considered “functional” and higher order functions because they don’t actually mutate the original array and rather return a new array?

Comment: That they don't mutate their arguments has nothing to do with them being higher-order or not.

Comment: You can say *Higher-order functions are functions that take other functions as arguments or return functions as their results.*